# How to change the application state to foreground when it is in background

Tags: ios, ios6

I want to programmatically invoke my running application which is currently in background state.

I know it can be done by local notification but is there any other way, any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: The user controls what app is in the foreground. It would be a horrible experience if 3rd party apps could force their way to the foreground.

Comment: Yes I agree maddy and thats why apple provided notification option for invoking background application. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well **YES** in a way. You can simply implement *push notifications* for your app wherein there will be a notification displayed from the top of your device . On clicking this notification, the app will open accordingly. This is done by default. I hope this is what you were asking. Otherwise, there is **NO** other way to get your app from the background to the foreground state without clicking the icon of the app.

Comment: Thanks IronManGill, I have already done this and its working as expected. I just want to cross check whether it can be done in other way

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not a such a way.

Answer (score 1):

As far as my knowledge directly we can't change app state from background to foreground programmatically. There are no other methods available other than Notifications.